# Need Help Using Instantiating External .NET Object in ANSI C!

Tags: c, .net, object, instantiation, dllimport

I'm working on an open source project that is written in low-level ANSI C (I have no control over this).  I am trying to integrate the Microsoft Office Interop functionality into the Windows build of this project.  Specifically, I would like to make use of these functions to generate Excel workbooks.

If this was in C# or C++, this wouldn't be a problem for me as I've done it numerous times.  But I am completely stumped on how to do this in low-level C!  The DLL I need to take this from is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll.  In C#, it would go something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static class Excel
{
    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application m_oExcelApp;
    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks m_oBooks;
    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook m_oBook;
    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet m_oSheet;
    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange;

    public static void MakeBook()
    {
        m_oExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        m_oExcelApp.Visible = false;
        m_oSheet = null;
        m_oBooks = null;
        excelRange = null;
```

....and so-on.  I would be really happy if I could just get this far!  But as far as I can tell, DllImport only allows you to import functions; i.e. I can't figure out how it would be used to *instantiate* an object within that DLL (i.e. creating an instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(), which is required to make any use of these libraries).

Please understand that I fully realize what a daunting task this is, and doing this in low-level C was NOT my choice!  But I'm stuck with it, I'm on a somewhat tight deadline, and if any of you are more versed in low-level C than I am and can help me port the above code over, I would be EXTREMELY grateful for your help!

Thanks!

EDIT:  I appreciate the conceptual advice, but what I *really* need is some example C code to show me how to actually make it happen!  Please guys, somebody has to be able to help me with this!  I don't need a lot, just a small example showing me how to do it in the context of what I'm trying to do, and I can handle it from there.

Comment: It looks like you'll need to host the CLR, then call CLR functions to instantiate your object.

Comment: I see.  Could you give me a code example of how this would be done?  My knowledge of ANSI C is still fairly rudimentary.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to wrap the object as an opaque handle, and then wrap the methods you want to use in C as COM functions that take the opaque handle. For more information, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx) might be a good place to start.

Comment: I see.  I understand conceptually what you're saying, but I still have no idea how to actually accomplish this in C using DllImport.  If anyone has an extra moment and can provide me with a simple code sample to at least get me started, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: I've been playing around with this in lieu of a follow-up response to my question, but so far I've had no luck.  Here's what I took your answer to mean:

Comment: Header File:   struct excel;
 void Application();

Comment: C File:   struct excel
 {
  [DllImport( "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll", EntryPoint="Application" )]
  void Application();
 }

Comment: As expected, this threw a C2032 compiler error because functions cannot be members of struct in C.  Switching to C++, again, is not one of my available options.  PLEASE HELP!!